# Django - how to return a variable in template to the view as a POST request

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to return a variable from my template to the view as a POST request. The variable is dynamic and defined by a jquery script. I dont really know much about javascript, so I dont know how to get the variable minutes and seconds to my view, so I can display them at the next site as a POST request.

Here is my template in which I want to get the variables minutes and seconds to my view:

```
{% extends "base_generic2.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <!-- Timer function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sec = 0;
        function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
        setInterval( function(){
            $("#seconds").html(pad(++sec%60));
            $("#minutes").html(pad(parseInt(sec/60,10)));
        }, 1000);
    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>

  <form action="results" id=results method="POST">

    <!-- after clicking on this button the minutes and seconds should also be sent as a POST request -->

    <div class="command">
      <button type="submit" name="ctest_submit">Submit solution</button>
    </div>

  </form>


{% endblock %}
```

And here is my view in which I want to use the minutes and seconds:

```
def viewtest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        minutes = request.POST['minutes']
        seconds = request.POST['seconds']
        return render(request, 'results.html', {'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds})

    else:

    #this section should not be important I think
```

How can I get the minutes and seconds to my view?

Answer (score 0):

Do an ajax post...

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/theurl/to/your/view",
  data: {'minutes':yourMinuteVariable, 'seconds':yourSecondsVAriable},
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I dont really know much about javascript, so how do I use this code? Do I just tag it as a script in my template and it should work?

Comment: Yes, but replace the url and variables with yours

Comment: i tried using it but I dont really know how to call the two variables "minutes" and "seconds". How can I call them from my html code?